# Checkbox in XtraGrid

Tags: c#, devexpress, xtragrid

I need to have a UI something like this.

> ```
>       Column1  Column2  Column3
> ```
>
> Row1      CHKBOX   CHKBOX   CHKBOX
>   Row2      CHKBOX   CHKBOX   CHKBOX
>   Row3      CHKBOX   CHKBOX   CHKBOX

Is there any way to implement this using XtraGrid ? Any example available online ?
I am using C#. What would be the best datastructure of datasource for such representation ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have a dataset with that xtragrid ?

1. If so go to that dataset, and to the datatable assigned to the xtragrid.
2. Click on each field in that datatable.
3. go to the DataType property, and set it to System.Boolean.

If you do not have a dataset.

1. Go to the xtragrid and run the designer.
2. Select the columns you need to be boolean, find the unboundType property, under Data.
3. And choose the boolean option.

Answer (score 0):

Since checkboxes usually represent boolean values.  Your data structure would be something

int ID
bool Column1
bool Column2
bool Column3